# q / KDB+ How to iterate through list of strings

Tags: kdb

I have recently began learning q programming language and I find it a little bit of a struggle since I am coming from the 'traditional' imperative, OOP, etc language background. I am trying to perform a seemingly simple task - find strings in list that contain specific character:

```
names:("Saint Denis";"Rhodes";"Strawberry";"Valentine")
```

How do I print all strings that contain letter "R"? Even better, both "R" and "r"?

The furthest I was able to get is this:

```
{[x]x?"o"} each names
```

What would be the correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`like`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/like/) keyword with a [regular expression](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/) like so:

```
q)names where names like "*[Rr]*"
"Rhodes"
"Strawberry"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like the below

```
q)names where "R" in/: names
"Rhodes"
q)names where any each "rR" in/: names
"Rhodes"
"Strawberry"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another couple of alternatives are:

```
q)names where "r" in'lower names
"Rhodes"
"Strawberry"

q)names where any"Rr"in'\:names
"Rhodes"
"Strawberry"
```